# How to mark a task as optional in GoCD?

Tags: go-cd

I need to make a request from a pipeline, which is optional on windows- and linux-based agents. The request may fail for whatever reason, but the pipeline should continue anyway - always.

All CICD-Systems I've worked with so far have the possibility to mark a task as optional or - more specifically - to ignore errors:

Example: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure

```
job1:
  stage: test
  script:
  - execute_script_that_will_fail
  allow_failure: true
```

I have *not* found a similar concept in GoCD - is there one I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `run_if` attribute of the task to achieve that. It takes `passed`, `failed` or `any`. Passed is the default value, that is only if the current task is passed it moves on to the next one. Failed is the exact opposite of this. I generally use it for setting up assertions within the job. Any is basically you don't care the outcome of that task. GoCD will not fail irrespective of the outcome of that task within the job.

```
exec:
  run_if: any
  working_directory: dir
  command: make
  arguments:
   - -j3
   - docs
   - install
```

References

- From GoCD's documentation - https://docs.gocd.org/current/advanced_usage/dev_conditional_task_execution.html
- If you're using the YAML to define your pipelines - https://github.com/tomzo/gocd-yaml-config-plugin#tasks

Comment: That seems like the equivalent of a `finally()` block - but that seems like the opposite of what I want. I'd have to mark everything *except* the task that allowed failure as `run_if: any`, correct? That way, if a task fails that I do not want to fail - or that should not run if a previous important task failed, it would run anyway.

Comment: By default all tasks are marked with `run_if: passed`. So each task is executed only if the previous task (if any) has passed. Assuming you've 3 tasks and the 2nd task might fail but you want to ignore them, mark the 3rd task as `run_if: any`. You don't have to update any other tasks. If the task that might fail is the last task, add a dummy task after that with `run_if: any` to work around. For GoCD to consider a job as successful it would want the last task in that job to be complete without any failure.

Comment: It seems that if any task in the job fails, even if the last task is `run_if: any`, gocd considers the entire job to have failed. I don't think this is a solution.